# How to filter page lists in the wagtail admin so editors only see pages from group there a part of?

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I have a menu item which lists all the pages at once from all the parent pages in the Wagtail admin. I would like there to display only the posts that are published by the users from the group that the currently logged in user is a part of.

I managed to use this code to limit the users to only view their own posts and think that this can be expanded to what i'm looking for.

```py
#admin.py

class PageAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    model = BlogPage
    menu_icon = "doc-full"
    menu_label = "All Posts"
    list_display = ("title", "date", 'owner')

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super().get_queryset(request)
        #only show articles from the current user
        return qs.filter(owner=request.user)

modeladmin_register(PageAdmin)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (untested):

`return qs.filter(owner__groups__in=request.user.groups.all())`

Comment: This seams to be working just need to test it fore users with multiple groups and Moderators. Thanks!